# Bounds for $\int_0^1 x^{\cos x+\sin x} dx$

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

Hello I am trying to show that $\frac{2}{5} \le \int_0^1 x^{\cos x+\sin x}dx \le \frac{1}{2}$ or to get better bounds.

Here is my try:$$I=\int_0^1 x^{\cos x}\cdot x^{\sin x} \,dx$$ By Cauchy inequality $$I^2\le \int_0^1 x^{\cos x} \,dx \cdot \int_0^1 x^{\sin x} \,dx$$ for $x\in [0,1]\,$ $$ 0\le \cos x \le 1$$ $$\,0\le \sin x \le 1$$ thus $$x^{\cos x} \le x$$ $$x^{\sin x} \le x$$ so $$\int_0^1 x^{\cos x} \,dx \le \frac{1}{2}$$ $$\int_0^1 x^{\sin x} \,dx \le \frac{1}{2}$$  Therefore $$I\le \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}} \le \frac{1}{2}$$ Is this correct? And what about the lower bound?

Comment: By a numerical method i got $$\int_{0}^{1}e^{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx\approx 0.43284 $$

Comment: By Cauchy inequality, you may get $$I^{2} \leq \int_{0}^{1} x^{2\cos x}dx \cdot \int_{0}^{1} x^{2\sin x}dx.$$ Also, $x^{\cos x}\leq x$ doesn't hold since $0\leq x\leq 1$. The inequality is reversed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\cos x+\sin x,\ x\in[0,1]$. $f$ is continuous function on $[0,1]$, so it has maximum and minimum value. It is easy to see that 
$$1\leq f(x)\leq \sqrt{2}.$$
So $$\frac{2}{5}<\sqrt{2}-1=\int_0^1 x^{\sqrt{2}}\ dx \leq\int_0^1 x^{\cos x+\sin x}  \,dx\leq\int_0^1 x\ dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: This was presumably the intended solution.

Comment: Maybe there are some typo, but I think the idea is right!